# uploading screenshots

Tags: support

Is it possible to uploads screen-shots from my laptop to this AskUbuntu forum? I need to do it in order to link my answer to it. I searched for the process in **formatting help**, but found none.

Comment: Try using an external site first, linking the images (e.g. http://imgur.com/)

Comment: okay. Will do :)

Comment: You may even edit this question completely by replacing the links & of course, explaining the issue. We'll help you further questioning and assisting

Comment: The issue is that some random guy was trying to install a software and was encountering a problem. I had the issue a few days back, so I wanted to help, I needed to upload a few screen-shots for that. Is it possible?

Comment: Err... exactly what is the error? There's a img bottom in all edition interfaces. If you use it you can upload stuff.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. There is no __error__, I tried to look for a way to upload screen-shots directly onto this posting arena, so that it would help someone else. I couldn't find a way to do it. So, I searched in the __formatting help__ forum space but there wasn't any mention of a local upload there either. So, I asked, if anyone knew about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a screenshot by clicking the `img` button or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

[image]

It will then allow you to select an icon from your computer or another webpage.

Also, don't worry about not having enough reputation to post images, just use the above method and put a [link](http://example.com) to the image. Someone else will edit it it in for you.

Comment: Okay, thank you...:)
But, if I'm commenting on someone else's post, then I think I need to link to some image hosting website, right??

Comment: @ubuntu_noob You *can* edit an answer/question, add an image there, then copy the image link into your comment.